# Finding R^2 for each row and rows previous

Tags: r, loops, for-loop

I have an X-Y table and wish to find the R^2 value for all of the rows, then subtract a row and perform the function again.
I have started with this function:

```
df<-data.frame(x=1:10,y=1:10)

R2<-function(df)
  for(i in length(df$x)){
  Rsq<-lm(x ~ y, data=df)
  print(Rsq)
}
```

So this gives me the R^2 for the whole data frame, I just can't seem to work out how to perform the function successively by subtracting a row each time.

Comment: Several things. 1. Function code should be in curly brackets. 2. Check if `for(i in length(df$x)` really iterates over what you think it iterates over (and read some things in for-loops in R. 3. You are printing the model, not returning anything.

Comment: Edited the code for curly brackets- typo. Indeed for(i in length(df$x)) {print (i)} only gives the number of the rows successively. I am confused.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming that what is wanted is to find the R-squared of y[-1] vs. x[-2], y[-2] vs. x[-2], etc.

```
sapply(1:nrow(df), function(i) summary(lm(y ~ x, df, subset = -i))$r.squared)
```

Note that we can get the adjusted R squared by replacing `r.squared` with `adj.r.squared` in the above code.

If you really want to write a loop which successively prints the R squared values then it would be done like this:

```
R2 <- function(df) {
  for(i in 1:nrow(df)) {
    Rsq <- summary(lm(x ~ y, data = df, subset = -i))$r.squared
    print(Rsq)
  }
}
R2(df)
```

Comment: Thank you for this comment both for the sapply and editing my code. This has helped. However the edit you have given to my code returns an error of : extra argument ‘ssubset’ is disregarded. It prints a results but only a single R^2 value

Comment: You have mistyped the code typing `ssubset` instead of `subset`.